# Python script to remove certain things form a string

Tags: python

i have a file with many lines like this,

```
>6_KA-RFNB-1505/2021-EPI_ISL_8285588-2021-12-02
```

i need to convert it to

```
>6_KA_2021-1202
```

all of the lines that require this change start in a >

The `6_KA` and the `2021-12-02` are different for all lines.

I also need to add an empty line before every line that i change in thsi manner.

Comment: Why did you edit out all the examples? Now your question is very confusing

Comment: the other part was pretty irrelevant

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: You changed the requirements from when I originally answered yourpost, but the below does what you are looking for. The principle remains the same: use regex to identify the parts of the string you are looking to replace. And then as you are going thru each line of the file create a new string based on the values you parsed out from the regex

```
import re

regex = re.compile('>(?P<first>[0-9a-zA-Z]{1,3}_[0-9a-zA-Z]{1,3}).*(?P<year>[0-9]{4})-(?P<month>[0-9]{2})-(?P<day>[0-9]{2})\n')

def convert_file(inputFile):
    with open(inputFile, 'r') as input, open('Output.txt', 'w') as output:
        for line in input:
            text = regex.match(line)
            if text:
                output.write("\n" + text.group("first") + '_' + text.group("year") + "-" + text.group("month") + text.group("day") + "\n")
            else:
                output.write(line)

convert_file('data.txt')
```

Comment: Sorry, but this code did not end up working,

Comment: The program does not seem to execute for some reason, although it shows no errors.

Comment: @AakifRehman The code does work so there should be some type of output when you execute the script. For example, it assumes there is a file in your current directory named data.txt which contains all of the data you want to parse. If this file does not exist you should see a FileNotFoundError otherwise you should see the Output.txt in your current directory. How exactly are you trying to run this script?

Comment: The program works fine, Thank you. except there is a problem. it only runs once.